# iTextSharp HTMLWorker img not found 404

Tags: itext

I got the problem that the HTMLWorker.ParseToList function will throw an exception ( 404 - not found ) when a tag like:

```
<img alt="none" src="/image.jpg" />
```

Has a deadlink in the src.I'd like it to just not load the image and go on.

Does anyone now a way to configure this or has similar solution in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The path must be absolute ex: c:\images\image.jpg

You can do it with

```
Server.MapPath(relativeUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `HTMLWorker` to include a filter to remove (or substitute) whichever HTML elements you want before passing your HTML to your extended `HTMLWorker`'s `ParseToList()` method.

Answer (score 0):

look into this thread

http://www.draggerco.com/node/2

works great for me...

i just replaced

```
string siteUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "");
```

with

```
string siteUrl = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath([your_path_for_images_in_string]);
```

** Note: for this, use HtmlWorker.Parse() method

Answer (score 0):

I'am fixed. But This;

c:\images\image.jpg as localhost:3524\images\image.jpg

```
<img alt="none" src="http://localhost:3524/image.jpg" />
```

Create your host configuration.

```
    html = html.Replace("img src=\"", "img src=\"http://localhost:3524");
```

it's worded.